# Need a way to decrease the current used by a stepper motor through a TMC2209 when it is idle

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, esp8266, stepper-driver

I am using an ESP8266 to control a stepper motor through TMC2209. In my use-case, the motor is idle 80% of the time. But i can't turn off the enable pin since i need the motor to still be fixed in its position. Is there a way to just decrease the current the motor is drawing while its idle?

Comment: Look at chapter 8 & 9, p 49-52 of the TMC2209 datasheet. There you see more information about how to control the current draw of the driver. 

You say that the motor is drawing current in the "Idle" state, but what I believe you mean is that you have the motor in a hold state, i.e. the rotor is locked and cannot be turned without applying some torque. If you decrease the amount of current used in the hold state, the amount of torque required to twist the rotor will also decrease.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at page 50 and 51 of the [DATASHEET](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2209_Datasheet_V103.pdf).

The setting you are looking for is "IHOLD".

It can take values from 0 to 31.  31 being full current.  You will have to test in your application for the minimum holding current that will work for you.

There is also an "automatic standstill current reduction" via pin 14.